# Unable to create repo using BitBucket 2.0 API

Tags: git, python-3.x, bitbucket-api

I am getting Bad Request when I try to create a new repo using Bitbucket API

```
def create_repo(self):

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    data = {
                   "scm": "git",
        "grant_type": "access_token",
        "project": {
            "key": 'US'
        },
        "access_token": self.get_access_token(),
        "username": self.username,
        "password": self.password,
    }

    r = requests.post('https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{teamname}/test1', headers=headers,
                      data=data)
```

Tried to change many things but, I am getting bad request each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [BitBucket API Authentication methods](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/authentication):

> Basic HTTP Authentication as per [RFC-2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) (Digest not supported).
>
> Note that Basic Auth with username and password as credentials is only available on accounts that have 2-factor-auth / 2-step-verification disabled.
> If you use 2fa, you should authenticate using OAuth2 instead.

So make sure first that you don't use 2fa.

Then check if the request sent does look like the one from the [/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug} `POST`](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D#post) documentation.